# MSSQL delete with output

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create an agent job that archives records from a logging table.  I created an archive table based on a create script from the original.  I am using the following SQL but, when I execute, it's telling me the columns in the columnlist don't exist.  Yet when I modify this as a select query using the same where clause it is definitely returning records.  Where am I going wrong?  (Screenshot here: https://www.screencast.com/t/JVaQ2Avh)

```
DELETE FROM log_an
OUTPUT [DELETED.deviceID]
      ,[DELETED.dSystem]
      ,[DELETED.dLogged]
      ,[DELETED.dDevice]
      ,[DELETED.bLateAdd]
      ,[DELETED.cv]
      ,[DELETED.fv]
      ,[DELETED.temp]
      ,[DELETED.temp2]
      ,[DELETED.humi]
      ,[DELETED.humi2]
      ,[DELETED.co2]
      ,[DELETED.co22]
      ,[DELETED.iaq]
      ,[DELETED.voc]
      ,[DELETED.light]
      ,[DELETED.colortemp]
      ,[DELETED.red]
      ,[DELETED.green]
      ,[DELETED.blue]
      ,[DELETED.ir]
      ,[DELETED.full]
      ,[DELETED.vis]
      ,[DELETED.lux]
      ,[DELETED.baro]
      ,[DELETED.sound]
      ,[DELETED.rssi]
      ,[DELETED.ta]
      ,[DELETED.ha]
      ,[DELETED.ca]
      ,[DELETED.ia]
      ,[DELETED.la]
      ,[DELETED.altitude]
INTO log_an_archive 
where deviceid=4 AND DATEDIFF( "M", dLogged, getdate() ) > 6
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM log_an
OUTPUT [DELETED].[deviceID]
      ,[DELETED].[dSystem]
...
```

Your brackets are in the wrong place.

- [DELETED].[deviceID] = deviceID column in DELETED psuedo-table
- [DELETED.deviceID] is a column called "DELETED.deviceID"